# Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...0.0","acorn-globals":'

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

Unfortunately, I'm having issues with installing react-native
I get this error while installing

```
Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...0.0","acorn-globals":'
```

I think the problem is with something called jest, because but when I try to install only jest,
I get the same error, I don't know what jest is I'm just starting to learn react-native .

here is the log files :

```
393 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...0.0","acorn-globals":'
393 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
393 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
393 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
393 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
394 verbose cwd D:\Dev\React-Native\Sektorian
395 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
396 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "jest" "babel-jest" "babel-preset-react-native" "react-test-renderer@16.3.1" "--save-dev" "--save-exact"
```

What do yo think the problem is ?

Comment: remove the node_modules folder and go to the directory where package.json is present and fire command npm install

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems and error related to NPM, you could try to solve it in this way:

- clear the cache for NPM `npm cache clean`.
- delete `node_modules`
- reinstall your dependencies using `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of error while trying `create-react-app <project_name> .`

For me, this worked:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then I uninstalled the required package:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Then reinstalled with --save flag and this seemed to solve the problem:

```
sudo install -g create-react-app --save
```

Hope that helps! Happy coding!